# Dropping a single table with Django app on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I have a Django app running on Heroku.

Usually I can just run `python manage.py dbshell` on my local machine and then do `DROP TABLE <app_table>`. But I can't do this on Heroku.

How can I do that for an app running on Heroku without deleting the whole database and resyncing?

Note: Heroku is a PostgreSQL db. I haven't been able to get Postgres working on Mountain Lion so transferring the database from my local machine isn't an option :(

Comment: Why are you want to drop table? Looks like you need [south](http://south.aeracode.org/). In case of some unusual application where it's required indeed, create custom management command that will drop/create/fill/whatsoever.

Comment: I want to basically add a column to that table. so thought I'd drop and resync since there's not much info in that table. ok i'll try those.... hopefully they're not too complicated to learn.

Comment: In case of modifying db schema you __should__ use south. Think of south as of a part of django.

Comment: South instead of nashvegas? which is easier?

Comment: Basic south usage is about two management commands (pretty easy comparing to modifyind db by hands). What about other migration tools, I vote for south because its more popualar. Here is [tuturial](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html) by the way. :)

Comment: Thanks! I'm following this tutorial right now :http://www.mikeball.us/blog/using-south-on-heroku-hosted-django-project. But I'm getting `Unknown command: 'convert_to_south'
` when I run  `python manage.py convert_to_south <app name>` .... any idea why? (Step 12) Everything prior to that was fine...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19776/discussion-between-melevir-and-user1328021)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [nashvegas](https://github.com/paltman/nashvegas), it has been reported [working on heroku](http://twitter.com/repustate/statuses/171091037031374849).

Also note that what you are trying to do is called "schema migration" and django allows [various solutions](http://blog.yourlabs.org/post/20833599582/django-schema-migrations-nashvegas-vs-south-vs).